# Call function in onCreate()?

Tags: android

When I try to call a function from onCreate, the app stops working.
All i am trying to do, it change the text in textview, when the activity loads. Help?

```
public class BellSchedules extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bell_schedules);
    BellSch(null);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.bell_schedules, menu);
    return true;
}

public void BellSch(View view)
{
    TextView bells = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    int date = (Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    String realDate = getString(date);
    //bells.setText(realDate);
    bells.setText("huehuehuehuehue");
}
```

Comment: Whats the LogCat crash?

Comment: What does "stops working mean"? If you get "Sorry, XXX has stopped", then you should post the logcat. This will show the exact cause of the error and enable us to help you try to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getString` method's argument is a `resId`, which needs to point to one of your resource ids. Reference here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString(int)

Try this instead:

```
String realDate = ""+date;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    // do your work
    return true;
}
```